# How can I add Patterns and colors in the same folder in color swatch panel in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I add Patterns and colors in the same folder in color swatch panel in Illustrator?
What I need to do is recoloring to switch between color scheme that contain pattern in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't**. The color groups folders in the Swatch Panel can only contain colors. There is no workaround to allow them to contain gradients or patterns.